# How iterate over rows in a dataframe dictionnary and change some values - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop

I have this dictionary of df:

```
DataFrameDict:
'A':                         
                       date_time    begin                            end
      2019-10-21 07:39:07.927729      NaT    2019-10-21  07:42:24.747350
      2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716      NaT    2019-10-21  07:42:02.574268
      2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327      NaT    2019-10-21  07:42:02.222821


'B':                         
                      date_time                             begin                           end
     2019-10-21 07:39:07.927729       2019-10-21  07:42:24.747350                           NaT    
     2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716       NaT                           2019-10-21  07:42:02.574268
     2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327       NaT                           2019-10-21  07:42:02.222821
```

I would like to do this : for each row of each dataframe, if begin[i] == NaT then begin[i] = date_time[i]
else: end[i] = date_time[i].

The result must be :

```
DataFrameDict:
'A':                         
                       date_time                           begin                            end
      2019-10-21 07:39:07.927729      2019-10-21 07:39:07.927729    2019-10-21  07:42:24.747350
      2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716      2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716    2019-10-21  07:42:02.574268
      2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327      2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327    2019-10-21  07:42:02.222821


'B':                         
                      date_time                             begin                           end
     2019-10-21 07:39:07.927729       2019-10-21  07:42:24.747350   2019-10-21 07:39:07.927729    
     2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716       2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716    2019-10-21  07:42:02.574268
     2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327       2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327    2019-10-21  07:42:02.222821
```

So I try this piece of code of mine :

```
 for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    for row in DataFrameDict[key].itertuples():
        if DataFrameDict[key].at[row.Index, 'begin'] == 'NaT':
            DataFrameDict[key].at[row.Index, 'begin'] = DataFrameDict[key].at[row.Index, 'date_time']
        else:
            DataFrameDict[key].at[row.Index, 'end'] = DataFrameDict[key].at[row.Index, 'date_time']
```

But it doesn't work...

Thanks for your time !

**UPDATE**
I tried your soluton Quang Hoang

```
for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    mask = DataFrameDict[key]['begin'].isna()
    DataFrameDict[key].loc[mask, 'begin'] = DataFrameDict[key]['date_time']
    DataFrameDict[key].loc[~mask, 'end'] = DataFrameDict[key]['date_time']
```

the data's results aren't correct.

Comment: `But it doesn't work...` - why? How is it deficient? Does it almost work?

Comment: it just fill the 'end' column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this function:

```
def fill_date(df):
    mask = df['begin'].isna()
    df.loc[mask,'begin'] = df['date_time']
    df.loc[~mask, 'end'] = df['date_time']

for df in [A,B]: fill_date(df)
```

Comment: `df.loc[~mask, 'end'] = df['date_time']` -> `df.loc[df['end'].isna(), 'end'] = df['date_time']` ?

Comment: @wwii Only fill `end` where `begin` is `NaT`, per OP's logic. OP did not specify that `end.isna()` is equal to `begin.notna()`.

Comment: I was looking at the desired result and it looks like `'end'` only gets *filled* when **it** is NA.

Comment: the logic is if begin is filled then copy the value of date_time in the 'end' value and vice versa.  Because one of the two is filled. But currently just the column end is filled.

Comment: You have both example, is the 'B' : the first row, the begin is filled then we filled the end with date_time value. In the second and third row we have end filled then we filled the begin with date_time.

Comment: @QuangHoang when i tried your code I have a problem with the end column, here on result :  1571643515363364096 but for the begin column it is the good result.